# JQuery Calling WCF: .ajax works while .post does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, post

While calling WCF service using ajax, .ajax works while .post not with error: The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.

Could someone tell the differences between these two calls?  Thanks!

```
//WCF
    [OperationContract]
    public ColumnSelector[] returnColumnInformation(string templateid, string userid)
    {
    }

// ColumnSelector
[DataContract]
public class ColumnSelector
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ColumnOrder { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ColumnDisplay { get; set; }

    public ColumnSelector()
    {
        ColumnName = "";
        ColumnOrder = "";
        ColumnDisplay = "";
    }

    public ColumnSelector(string _name, string _order, string _display)
    {
        ColumnName = _name;
        ColumnOrder = _order;
        ColumnDisplay = _display;
    }
}

// working:
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AjaxService1.svc/returnColumnInformation",
            data: JSON.stringify({templateid: "1", userid: "300"}) ,
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        })
        .done(function (msg) {
         alert("POST Data Saved: " + msg);
        });


// not working: The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message
// formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $("#AjaxPost").click(function () {
            $.post("AjaxService1.svc/postColumnInformation",
            {templateid: "1", userid: "300"},
            function (data, status) {
                alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            },
            "json"               
            )
             .done(function () {
                 alert("second success");
             })
              .fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                  alert(err.Message);
              })
                .always(function () {
                    alert("finished");
                });
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The url you are requesting in the .post method is different from the url in the .ajax method, it is likely due to something going wrong with that particular url. The .post usage looks correct and should produce the same result as the .ajax usage. [Reference.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)